# Validation Messages GWT i18n Encoding Issue

Tags: java, maven, gwt, encoding, internationalization

I use Java, GWT, Spring, Maven and Tomcat. Field validation messages stored in .properties files each of them saved UTF-8 encoding. One of these files has words written in Russian, so when I change web interface language to Russian I receive validation message in wrong encoding like this:

Ð½Ðµ Ð´Ð¾Ð»Ð¶Ð½Ð¾ Ð±ÑÑÑ null

(right message from file looks like: не должно быть null)

Localization messages provides by class which extends com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Messages

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your host HTML file contain the charset=utf8 content type in the meta tag in the header:
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Before it was edited you wrote about native2ascii tool. I expanded your solution and try to use Native2Ascii Maven plugin. I'll post solution later because of my rating.

Comment: I edited my comment because I remembered that GWT properties files support UTF-8 (versus Java properties that only support ASCII). You do not necessarily need native2ascii tool in GWT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with Native2Ascii Maven plugin. This problem was solved by choosing right working directory ('target' directory not 'source') and right phase of plugin execution. 'test' phase works for me. So files are copying in target directory and then converting in ANSI encoding, but original files remain unchanged.Here my configuration:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      [...]
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>native2ascii-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </executions>
          <execution>
            <execution>
                    <id>native2ascii-utf8-validation</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>native2ascii</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF8</encoding>
                        <includes>
                            <include>ValidationMessages*.properties</include>
                        </includes>
                        <workDir>${basedir}/target/classes/app/validation</workDir>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
          </execution>
          [...]
        </executions>
        [...]
      </plugin>
      [...]
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```